# Why is my SQL Left Join not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a basic left join.
Structure of the tables are :

AGR_USERS : User (UNAME) - > AGR_NAME (Role) relationship - 1 to many

AGR_AGRS : Role (AGR_NAME) - > Child Role (CHILD_AGR) relationship - 1 to many

However the results are not accurate, since the query is not identifying the child roles(CHILD_AGR) present within the role (AGR_NAME) for users (UNAME).

Could you please help me to resolve the same. Below is the query which i am using.

---

```
SELECT 
agr_users.UNAME, 
agr_users.AGR_NAME, 
AGR_AGRS.CHILD_AGR, 

FROM AGR_USERS LEFT JOIN AGR_AGRS
ON AGR_AGRS.AGR_NAME=agr_users.AGR_NAME
```

**** MS-SQL server

Below is table data

Table 1 :AGR_AGRS ( role - child role table )

```
AGR_NAME         CHILD_AGR
abc                       x
abc                       y
```

Table 2 : AGR_USERS ( User - role table)

```
UNAME      AGR_NAME
nik              abc
```

Expected result : ( User - role - child role )

```
UNAME       AGR_NAME    CHILD_AGR
nik                abc                  x
nik                abc                  y
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have updated my question with sample data, desired results and the database i.e. MS-SQL sever. Appreciate your help

Comment: Your existing query already produces the expected result, assuming reasonable data types for the columns, as demonstrated here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34a4a8/1 If you're getting an empty result set then there's something going on beyond what's spelled out in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very straightforward query.  The below should get you the full list:

```
select u.UNAME
      ,a.AGR_NAME
      ,a.CHILD_AGR
from AGR_USERS as u
    left join AGR_AGRS as a
        on u.AGR_NAME = a.AGR_NAME
```

If it does not, your environment must be different to how you have represented it within your question.